# How to modify the value of numpy array based on another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array. I want to modify one array index by the chosen elements of another array. For example:

```
import numpy as np
t1 = np.ones((10,3))
t2 = np.arange(10)
t1[np.where(t2>5)][:,2] = 10
print(t1)
```

What I want t1 is:

```
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 10.],
       [1., 1., 10.],
       [1., 1., 10.],
       [1., 1., 10.]])
```

But the output of t1 is:

```
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

What the problem there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most pythonic way to do this is probably

```
t1[:, 2] = np.where(t2 > 5,       # where t2 > 5
                    10,           # put 10
                    t1[:, 2])     # into the third column of t1
```

Besides added clarity, for very large objects this will have a time benefit, as there is no creation of an intermediate indexing array `np.where(t2 > 5)` and no resulting intermediate callbacks to that `python` object - everything is done in-place with c-compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

It's backwards, it should be:

```
t1[:,2][np.where(t2>5)] = 10
```

output:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1., 10.],
       [ 1.,  1., 10.],
       [ 1.,  1., 10.],
       [ 1.,  1., 10.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
t1[np.where(t2>5), 2] = 10
```

*Syntax*: `array[<row>, <col>]`